# how to make the server get pdf submissions

Tags: pdf, submit

I have a pdf with submit button, i want when any one press submit after filling the form to collect submissions on my web server.

How to do that?, thanks

Comment: Are you creating this PDF? If so, please provide example. Or are you looking for general solution? What application is being used to open/view the PDF? Or are you looking to handle any PDF application?

Comment: Unless you have control over the PDF viewer that's used to open the PDF, you won't be able to make this work.